# How to update a variable using a function with no arguments and no return type in C

Tags: c

I know that If a function has no argument & only return type (say int), then I can change my int variable by assigning the function to my variable as below,

```
main()
{
  int var_name;
  var_name = func();
  printf("My variable value is updated as : %d", a);
}

func()
{ return 100; }
```

Also I know that If I have my function's return type as void, with no arguments, then I can only print the value inside the function itself and cannot return anything in turn.

But, my doubt is, is there anything else that I can do to update my var_name by calling a function with no arguments & no return type ?
ie., void func(void); by using something like pointer concepts ??
I could not able to find the exact answer for the same by my searches among so many websites.. I will be very grateful if someone can help me out finding whether I can do it by this way or not,.

Thanks,.

Comment: *Why* would you like to do that?

Comment: "by assigning the function to my variable" - nope, `func()` is not the function itself; it means the result of calling it.

Comment: On a side note, what decades-old tutorial are you following and why?

Comment: A local variable is private to the function. You have to use the `&` operator on it to make the compiler guarantee that it has an adress, otherwise it could be stored in a register or even be optimized away.

Comment: As of now, I am trying to understand which is the easiest way and good practice to manage memory size of my program. Hence, out of exitation, I would like to know that.. @5gon12eder

Comment: Thank you, understood. I wanted to know the other methods too and hence posted the question. Just understood that it is not a good practice to do so. Thanks.. @immibis

Comment: Yeah, this method I know.. Thank you for your in depth explanation.. @potrzebie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no *good* way to do that. If you want the function to modify a local variable, you should probably change the function so it either returns a value that you can assign to the variable, or takes the variable's address as an argument.

But if you don't mind writing some ugly code, you can define a global (file-scope) pointer variable, assign the local variable's address to the global pointer, and then use that to modify the variable inside the function.

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *global_pointer;

void func(void) {
    *global_pointer = 42;
}

int main(void) {
    int local_variable = 0;
    global_pointer = &local_variable;
    func();
    printf("local_variable = %d\n", local_variable);
}
```

It's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot his way. For example, if you refer to the pointer after the calling function has terminated (and the local variable no longer exists), you'll have undefined behavior.

This technique can actually be useful if you need to make a quick *temporary* change in a body of code in which you can't make major interface changes. Just don't do it in code that will be maintained by anyone else -- and wash your hands afterward.

Comment: Thank you Keith, for your valuable suggessions, I wont be using it in my code as it is not a good practice to do so. But still I just wanted to the other methods too, out of exitation.

Comment: I could not able to understand the term "interface changes". Could you please tell me what do you mean by "interface changes"??

Comment: @Denise adding parameters to a function mainly. In a really big program you often can't change certain things without breaking other things. For example if you added a parameter to a function you'd have to change all the declarations of that function (hopefully only one) and all the calls to that function.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to modify a local variable in `main`, from a function with no arguments and no return value, if there's a global pointer to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *p;

void func() {
    *p = 6;
}

int main() {

    int a = 5;
    p = &a;
    func();
    printf("a = %d\n", a); // prints: a = 6

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working fine..                                                                   Could you please help me to do the same for an array ? I had tried as below, but it is showing segmentation fault (while running it) after a successful compilation.                                                                           int *p;

void func() {
    *p = 6;
}

int main() {

    int arr[10];
    memcpy(&arr,0,sizeof(arr));
    memcpy(p,0,sizeof(*p));
    arr[3]=1;
    p = &arr[3];
    func();
    printf("a = %d\narr[3] = %d", a, arr[3]); 
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Denise An array is not the same as a pointer. When you do `memcpy(p, 0, sizeof(*p))`, you have not initialized p. This line of code does not modify `p`; it modifies the thing `p` points to.

Comment: Thank you so much, with memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p)), the expected result can be achieved.. for array also, to initialize, I need to use memset only.. @immibis

Comment: @Denise Or you could just use `p = NULL;`... or just remove that line entirely, since the very next line sets `p` to something else anyway.

Comment: But still, initializing a variable is a good practice rite ?? @immibis

Comment: @Denise there is no such thing as a good practice or a bad practice. What is bad is following things religiously instead of using your judgement, or not using common sense. Does adding `memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p))` make your code any easier to understand, faster, or more portable? If not, then what is the reason for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have global variable

```
int var_name;
void func();

int main()
{
   func();
   printf("%d\n",var_name);
} 

void func()
{
   var_name = 20;
}
```

But if your variable is local to `main()` then this can't be done.

There are two ways to modify the value of var_name.

1. Make changes in the calling function and return the value.( which you have already shown)
2. Pass the address of the var_name to the function and have pointer as arguement in the `func(int *p)` and modify the value inside the `func()`

Thats it!! No other way this can be done.